# Unable to add an azure devops team as approvers for a Pipeline Environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to add an azure devops team as approver for a pipeline environment using POST api request. It gives an NullException pointing that configuration cant be null. In the Request Payload only one parameter is null which in uniqueName.

Now, when adding individual users as approver it generates uniqueName which is their email address but when adding a team the payload which I retrived using network options of a browser has uniqueName parameter as null.

Comment: solved it, Just add the name of group/team without any special characters.